# Check a string for certain character values in C?

Tags: c, string, char

I want the user to type a string that **contains only 'P' and 'K' characters**. So that's my string, declared inside the main function,

```
char string[30];
```

and that's a function that returns 1 if the string completes that criteria or 0 if it does not:

```
int isStringValid(char **string){
    int i=0;
    while(*(string+i)!='\0'){
        if(*(string+i)!='P' || *(string+i)!='K'){
            return 0;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I am getting the string from the user with scan f, but the isStringValid function does not seem to work properly. It returns only false whatever string I type!

```
int main(){
char string[30];

scanf("%s", string);
        if(isStringValid(&string)){
            printf("Job Done!\n");
        }else{
            printf("Not recognised!\n");
        }
}
```

Any ideas why its not working?

Comment: You should be passing in `char *string` rather than `char **string`.

Comment: Probably because it contains one of the newline characters (`'\r'` or `'\n'`).

Comment: BTW, you should use `&&` there, not `||` (because `'P' != 'K'`).

Comment: And BTW, you should change the function to take `char*`, not `char**`.

Comment: @barakmanos This usage of `scanf()` won't store newline characters.

Comment: The type of `&string` is `char (*)[30]`, not `char**`.

Comment: `int isStringValid(char * string) { return strlen(string) == strspn(string, "PK"); }`

Comment: The `K` should be in quotes as well, ie: `'K'`

Comment: @mikeyq6: Will it terminate the character array with the null-character?

Comment: Your compiler must have warned you about your code. Pay attention to the compiler messages, they're not just there for a laugh

Comment: Guys I used double pointer because I want to change the value that is stored in the char string[30]

Comment: @DevSolar or even `return !string[strspn(string, "PK")]  ;`

Comment: @joop: Nice. Even better performance-wise.

Comment: @joop that's got to be worth whatever SO's equivalent of Reddit Silver is

Comment: It is a classic, I didn't invent it. Once you've seen it, you'll remember it (given some knowledge of stdlib etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `isStringValid()` function

- The type of argument should be `char*` because it is normal to pass pointer to string to process.
- `K` is undefined. `'K'` is character code of `K`.
- Write "If `*(string+i)` is **n**eigher `'P'` n**or** `'K'`".
- Using `size_t` for the counter is better in this case.

In `main()` function

- You should specify `void` as arguments.
- You should write return value explicitly for readability.
- You should limit maximum length to read to avoid buffer overrun.
- You should check if the reading is successful.
- You should pass the pointer to the string since argument type of `isStringValid()` is changed.

corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int isStringValid(char *string){
    size_t i=0;
    while(*(string+i)!='\0'){
        if(!(*(string+i)=='P' || *(string+i)=='K')){
            return 0;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(void){
    char string[30];

    if (scanf("%29s", string) != 1){
        printf("Read error!\n");
    }else if(isStringValid(string)){
        printf("Job Done!\n");
    }else{
        printf("Not recognised!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now, you could take it one step forward and generate the format string `"%29s"` based on `sizeof(string)`.

Comment: we could debate the input method until the cows come home... maybe `fgets` would be preferable, all depends on whether OP wants spaces to be significant, etc. etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int isStringValid(char* str)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; str[i]=='P' || str[i]=='K'; i++)
    {
    }
    if (str[i] == '\0')
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might also need to address OP's line `if(isStringValid(&string)){`

Comment: OK, I think I'll delete this answer due to @Skemelio's comment to the question (not really sure about OP's purpose).

Comment: nah don't delete it, the guy doesn't understand that passing `char *` allows the contents of the char array to be charged

Comment: @M.M: Yeah, there are several things that aren't really clear here, hard to address all of them... Also, I'm not really sure about the purpose, see my previous comment.

Comment: @Skemelio: No problem. BTW, at the end of the function, you can simply `return str[i] == '\0'`.

Comment: Thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Only_PK_present(char *str)
{
for(    ; *str == 'K' || *str == 'P'; str++ ) {;}
return !*str;
}

int Only_PK_present1(char *str)
{
for ( ; *str ; str++) {
        if (*str == 'K') continue;
        if (*str == 'P') continue;
        break;
        }
return !*str;
}

int Only_PK_present2(char *str)
{
do      {
        if (*str != 'K' && *str != 'P' ) break;
        } while (*str++);
return !*str;
}

// Or even shorter :

#include <string.h>

int Only_PK_present0(char *str)
{
return !str[strspn(str, "KP")];
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
printf("%d %d %d %d\n"
        , Only_PK_present(argv[1])
        , Only_PK_present1(argv[1])
        , Only_PK_present2(argv[1])
        , Only_PK_present0(argv[1])
        );
return 0;
}
```

When compiled with at least `-O2`, GCC will inline strspn(), and produces the following beauty for Only_PK_present0():

```
.globl Only_PK_present0
        .type   Only_PK_present0, @function
Only_PK_present0:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        movl    8(%ebp), %eax
        jmp     .L23
.L24:
        addl    $1, %eax
.L23:
        movzbl  (%eax), %edx
        cmpb    $75, %dl
        je      .L24
        cmpb    $80, %dl
        je      .L24
        testb   %dl, %dl
        sete    %al
        movzbl  %al, %eax
        popl    %ebp
        ret
        .size   Only_PK_present0, .-Only_PK_present0
```